# Linksys WAG54G Win8 Wireless Issue

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

I'm trying to connect up a Win8 Toshiba Laptop to a WAG54G wireless router. When I browse in Win8 for wireless networks, I can see other surrounding networks, but not my SSID.

I have tested with my iPhone 4S and a Windows 7 Desktop which can both see and connect to the network without a problem, so I'm thinking this might be a Win8 issue? A friend has recently tried with his Toshiba Win8 Laptop as well, which also didn't work.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What encryption mode are you using? WEP? WPA2-AES?

Comment: Hi David, this router supports WEP, WPA Pre-Shared and WPA RADIUS, no WPA2. Currently using WPA Pre-Shared Key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....instead of looking for the SSID in Windows 8, put it in manually. This could be a glitch (most like is) with Windows 8. Hopefully, they will create a future update to correct this issue. Also, *do* you have the latest updates installed?

Comment: Thanks Jay, I ran the updates for Windows 8 as there was about 10 or so, but this didn't help. When I added the network manually, it was unable to connect when attempting. See below for what eventually resolved for me.